# Excel: counting data for different days of different weeks ( variable rows count )

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

I have a report with data for different dates. 
As I have a daily report, I need to sum the quantity of data ( Paid, Done ) column for an every specific week. 
With the help of Weeknum I detected the number of a week, and now I need to calculate the sum of this data for a specific week. 
How can I accomplish that? 
I tried SUMIF - it didn't help.
[image]

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this

Comment: I don't need extra table, just to calculate sum of Paid, Done data for a specific week.

Comment: If you're having a problem with SUMIF it would help to show what you tried...

Comment: You can use the function Subtotal from the "Data" tab. (Which creates a kind of a pivot table as well ...)